# Slick Slider with Slider Synching and Sliding only via Arrows

Tags: jquery, slick.js

So in the official documentation of the [slick-slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in the **Slider Syncing** section the bottom slider is moving when clicking on a slide.

Is it possible to make the bottom slider only slide on arrow, the left or the right, click?

I have searched the documentation, but could not find anything about this.

[image]

The code from the documentation:

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch *focusOnSelect* from true to false to disable focus on selected element

Regards

Comment: This does not change the image at the slider on top though. Do you know if there is no other way but to implement this manually?

Comment: Hi, can you provide how are you make the code?
However you will need two separated sliders. The first one with "slidesToShow" to 1, this is the bigger slider and will show the content. The second one is the navigation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).